# SQL HELP... CONVERT(int, CONVERT(datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float, getdate())))

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am having a problem adjusting this part of my SQL statement:

```
HAVING dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(datetime, 
                                                  FLOOR(CONVERT(float, GETDATE()))) + 2)
```

Normally, the page that uses this statement just lists the amount of sales for today, I want to switch the `GETDATE()` to a date that I declare. I tried all different formats and none have worked

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to do?  This seems overly convoluted.

Comment: Also what RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: Yes, I have an ASP page that displays my companies total sales for today and builds a table. In the database the date is stored as 39734 which is equal to 13Oct08. I need a way to convert a variable/parameter to the 39734 format.

Comment: or for now i just want a way to convert any date, besides getdate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DATEADD/DATEDIFF method of setting the time portion to midnight of the current date - it's the fastest means, and casting to FLOAT can be unreliable:

```
HAVING BOOKINGS.dbo.BOOKED = CONVERT(INT, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0))+2
```

Then, you can set your own date easily if you use a variable (@var in this example, within a stored procedure or function):

```
DECLARE @var DATETIME

SELECT ...
HAVING BOOKINGS.dbo.BOOKED = CONVERT(INT, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @var), 0))+2
```

This assumes @var is a DATETIME data type.  Otherwise, you'll need to use a date format SQL Server will implicitly convert to a DATETIME -- or use [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to explicitly convert the value.

Comment: this works great when i type in the date i want to show up into the query, but could you help with declaring the @var I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: I added a little more detail - [this link provides more detail](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3087431/T-SQL-Programming-Part-1---Defining-Variables-and-IFELSE-logic.htm)

Comment: hmmmm. I get a ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' 

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed. 

/msd/date.asp, line 37

Comment: @NEWprogrammer: I specified that this is done via a stored procedure or function - you submit @var as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

if you want you to give your own date you could do this instead of getdate() which gives current system timestamp.

```
Cast('2010-11-04 13:28:00.000' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
declare @myDate as datetime
set @myDate = '11/2/2010'

. . .

HAVING dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED = CONVERT(int, CONVERT(datetime, 
                                                  FLOOR(CONVERT(float, @myDate ))) + 2)
```

That should do it, and it should automatically do the type conversion on your date string used in the set statement, or you could just pass in a datetime parameter if this is in a stored procedure.

Comment: that look good but my select statement is in an asp (not asp.net)page and  in a selectdata= "select......" where would i put the declare @myDate as datetime 
set @myDate = '11/2/2010' 
it doesn't work when i put it in the begining of my query.